# How to read/extract signature details field from a signed PDF using java

Tags: java, pdf, openssl, itext, pkcs#7

As I'm working on an initiative project which verifies whether the document produced by the customer is tampered or not? Whose objectives are as follows:
1.To check the data integrity of content provided in the signed PDF ?
2.To validate whether the signature is tampered or not?
3.Also verifying whether the series of CA is valid by ensuring the revocation list

I've gone through e-sign API document, Basics of PDF,Basics of X.509 certificate, OpenSSL tool (which helped only viewing X.509 certificate and not #PKCS7 standard format)
So can anyone please let me know How can I extract/read the signature dictionary from the signed PDF using Java?
Any other tool to achieve my objective is also okay but since I'm using java as language to code, it would be preferable in java.
Thanks in advance!